# $S_m(F)=\{a\in F:a^{p^m}=a\}$. $S_m (F)$ is a subfield of the field $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

Consider $S_m(F)=\{a\in F:a^{p^m}=a\}$

$F$ is a field of order $p^n$ and $m$ divides $n$.

how can you show that $S_m  (F)$ is a subfield   of the field $F$?

I can show that $S_m  (F)-0$ is a multiplicative cyclic group. But how can I show that $S_m  (F)$ is a additive group        as well.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: -1 What is $F$? This is false in general; take $F=\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: edited..@Servaes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha,\beta \in S_m(F)$, we have, by Freshman's dream,
\begin{align*}
(\alpha+\beta)^{p^k}-(\alpha+\beta) & = \alpha^{p^k}+\beta^{p^k} -(\alpha+\beta)\\
                         & =0, \\
(\alpha\beta)^{p^k} -\alpha\beta & =\alpha^{p^k}\beta^{p^k}-\alpha\beta \\
                      & = (\alpha^{p^k}-\alpha)\beta^{p^k}+\alpha(\beta^{p^k}-\beta)\\
                      & =0.
\end{align*}
Hence sum and product are again in $S_m(F)$. In the same way, $-\alpha\in S_m(F)$ for $p>2$. For $p=2$ we trivially have $-\alpha=\alpha$.

Comment: Can you please state what the theorem is ? I was searching but some theory namely   Freshmans dream' popping up.@Dietrich Burde

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355873/proof-of-freshmans-dream-in-commutative-rings) for Freshman's Dream. This is what I meant.